# Update query performance with Hibernate

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

We are examining 2 different methods to do our entities updates:

1. "Standard" updates - Fetch from DB, set Fields, persist.
2. We have a Query for each entity that looks like this:

   ```
   String sqlQuery =  "update Entity set entity.field1 = entity.field1, entity.field2 = entity.field2, entity.field3 = entity.field3, ....  entity.fieldn = entity.fieldn"
   ```

   We receive the fields that changed (and their new values) and we replace the string fields (only those required) with the new values. i.e. something like :

   ```
   for each field : fields {
         sqlQuery.replace(field.fieldName, getNewValue(field));
   }
   executeQuery(sqlQuery);
   ```

Any ideas if these options differ in performance to a large extent? Is the 2nd option even viable? what are the pros / cons?

Please ignore the SQL Injection vulnerability, the example above is only an example, we do use PreparedStatements for the query building.

Comment: The biggest here maintaince (why reinvent the wheel) and your solution is open for SQL injection attacks. You should NEVER use string replacement/concat to generate SQL always use a `PreparedStatement` with placeholders for it. If you want to know the performance difference, test. In general I wouldn't bother to write my own, development will be harder (and makes you wonder why do you want to use an ORM tool at all?).

Answer (score 0):

And build a mix solution?

First, create a hasmap .

Second, create a new query for a PreparedStament using before hasmap (for avoid SQL injection)

Third, set all parameters.

The O(x)=n, where n is the number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

1. The first solution is much more flexible You can rely on Hibernate [dirty checking mechanism](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/) for generating the right updates. That's one good reason why an ORM tool is great when writing data.
2. The second approach is no way way better because it might generate different update plans, hence you can't reuse the PreparedStatement statement cache across various column combinations. Instead of using string based templates (vulnerable to SQL injections) you could [use JOOQ instead](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.4/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/update-statement/). JOOQ allows you to reference your table columns in Java, so you can build the UPDATE query in a type-safe fashion.